# expand combobox in winforms

Tags: c#, combobox

I need to change a Winforms application. I am beginner with c #.
Can someone help me understand what is done here:

```
Combobox1.SelectedIndex == 0 ? CustomerType.pricelist: CustomerType.newpricelist
```

In the combobox, these 2 are now selectable
How do I proceed when a 3rd is added?

```
Combobox1.SelectedIndex == 0 ? CustomerType.pricelist: CustomerType.newpricelist : CustomerType.oldpricelist
```

this dosn't work

Comment: A simple [`switch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement would suffice.

Comment: Would also be a possibility. The answer from ikram is more suitable for my solution as it can be directly given to a method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = Combobox1.SelectedIndex == 0 ? CustomerType.pricelist
         : Combobox1.SelectedIndex == 1 ? CustomerType.newpricelist
         : CustomerType.oldpricelist
```